# How to check if specific datetime was not used using multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

There are 3 tables: **buildings**, **rooms**, **reservations**.

1 building = n rooms
1 room = n reservations

TABLE BUILDINGS - **ID**(int), **name**(varchar)
TABLE ROOMS - **ID**(int), **building_id**(int)
TABLE RESERVATIONS - **ID**(int), **room_id**(int), **date_start**(datetime), **date_end**(datetime)

### Buildings table example

```
<pre>
ID    name
1     Building A
2     Building B
3     Building C
</pre>
```

### Rooms table example

```
<pre>
ID    building_id
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     3
</pre>
```

### Reservations table example

```
<pre>
ID    room_id     date_start            date_end  
1     1           2014-08-09 14:00:00   2014-08-09 14:30:00
2     1           2014-08-09 14:30:00   2014-08-09 15:30:00
3     3           2014-08-09 16:30:00   2014-08-09 17:30:00
4     2           2014-08-09 16:00:00   2014-08-09 17:00:00
5     3           2014-08-09 16:00:00   2014-08-09 16:30:00
</pre>
```

### Question

How to filter all buildings which have atleast 1 room available at the specific date and time?

For example we want to filter all buildings which have atleast 1 available room at 2014-08-09 16:00:00 until 2014-08-09 17:00:00. In this case it will show that **Building A** AND **Building C** are available. **Building A** has 1 free room and **Building B** also has 1 free room, because there is no reservation on that room.

Can someone help me out on this one? I just can not figure it out with a single MySQL query to get all buildings. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to connect the `rooms` table to the `reservations` table, with the time condition in the `on` clause.  Then, look where there are no matches -- these are rooms that are available.

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, COUNT(*) as NumRoomsAvailable
FROM buildings b JOIN
     rooms r
     ON b.id = r.building_id LEFT JOIN
     reservations rv
     ON rv.room_id = r.id AND
        '2014-08-09 16:00:00' BETWEEN rv.date_start AND rv.date_end
WHERE rv.room_id is null
GROUP BY b.id;
```

The final step is just aggregating by the building, rather than listing each available room out separately.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I have an additional question if possible. Can we filter buildings only by selected date (if it has atleast 1 available room on selected day in any hour)? Buildings working hours may be different.

Comment: @user3924829 . . . I think that is more appropriate as a separate question.  Nothing in the current question mentions building operating hours.

Comment: Ok, will do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT b.name,r.id,rv.date_start,rv.date_end FROM buildings b
LEFT JOIN rooms r ON b.id = r.building_id 
LEFT JOIN reservataions rv ON rv.room_id = r.id
WHERE  '2014-08-09 16:00:00' BETWEEN rv.date_start AND rv.date_end
```